# Какой смысл в дробном бэкапе?

Tags: резервное-копирование, hosting, google-cloud

Хостинг Гугла копирует данные 3.3 раза. 0.3х - это как? И зачем?

> Because persistent disk storage has 3.3x data redundancy, each write
>   has to be written 3.3 times.

Comment: Это означает, что одна операция записи равняется 3.3 операциям ввода-вывода в секунду. Ключевое здесь **В СЕКУНДУ**. То есть это такой искусственный параметр для вычисления других данных. Как, например, в час пик в метро проходят 33 человека за 10 секунд = 3.3 человека в секунду. но мы то понимаем, что людей может быть только целое число =)

Comment: Там ничего про "в секунду" нет. Просто 3.3 раза.

Comment: https://github.com/cobookman/og-gcp/blob/master/content/guide/compute_engine.md

Comment: Ну да там тоже самое и написано: "Persistent disks have a 3.3x data redundancy. Each write is written 3.3 times". То что эти 3.3 раза умножают потом на IOPS для расчёта производительности не привязывает этот коэффициент к секундам. Это 3.3 копии данных.

Comment: вы тут? мне прямо самому интересно стало =)